# Infinite loop with cocos2d

Tags: ios, loops, cocos2d-iphone, a-star

I am using sqlboy's [A star Path Finding code](https://github.com/sqlboy/tiled-games/tree/master/src) for my enemy sprites to follow my main character.. Enemy sprite should be following the main sprite infinitely but I am not sure how I can do that..

I am using the following code for that..

```
curPoint = [self tileCoordForPosition:ccp(enemy.sprite.position.x, enemy.sprite.position.y)];
nextPoint = [self tileCoordForPosition:ccp(killer.sprite.position.x, killer.sprite.position.y)];

[pathFinder moveSprite:enemy.sprite from: curPoint to:nextPoint atSpeed:0.3f];
```

If I use this code in my init method, then it's called once only and if my killer sprite moves, enemy will not be following it..

If I use this code in my `update:(ccTime)dt` method, then, it never moves for some reason.. Where can I use this code to make my enemy sprite to move infinitely? Thanks..

Comment: Is the `update:` method actually being continually called?

Answer (score 1):

To use `update:` method, use

```
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

for example, in your onEnter method. Just don't forget to unschedule update later with

```
[self unscheduleUpdate];
```

I mean something like

```
@interface MyNode : CCNode
{
}
@end

@implementation MyNode

- (void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    [self scheduleUpdate];
}

- (void) onExit
{
    [super onExit];

    [self unscheduleUpdate];
}

- (void) update:(ccTime) dt
{
    // this method will be called every tick
    // if you need to update something, make it here
}

@end
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.. can u please give me an example.. i am new to cocos2d..